# perl regex mach and list

Tags: regex, perl

I want a to open a log file with perl, use regex to find what I want and then list only the path that are below the text "# Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP Exploit [P0008]]:"

The sript shoul only list this path:

```
/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/141163.php
/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/images/120541.php
/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/language/200724.php
/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/components/com_mynetwork/228469.php
```

Original log file

```
# Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP Exploit [P0008]]:
'/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/141163.php'
# Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP Exploit [P0008]]:
'/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/images/120541.php'
# Regular expression match = [symlink\s*\(]:
'/home/axacert/public_html/administrator/components/com_akeeba/akeeba/engines/archiver/jpa.php'
# Regular expression match = [symlink\s*\(]:
'/home/axacert/public_html/administrator/components/com_akeeba/akeeba/engines/archiver/zip.php'
# Regular expression match = [decode regex: 1]:
'/home/axacert/public_html/administrator/components/com_director/includes/stats.php'
# Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP Exploit [P0008]]:
'/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/language/200724.php'
# Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP Exploit [P0008]]:
'/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/components/com_mynetwork/228469.php'
```

I have basic perl skills, I know how to use regex but I don't know how to tell perl if the string mach to list only the path below the string and nothig else.

All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: What did you get so far? Can you post the code where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should achieve what you're after:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use File::Slurp;

my @file = read_file('test.txt'); # Read file into an array (you don't have to use file::slurp)
my $match=("# Known exploit"); # The thing you want to match on

for my $i (0 .. $#file) { # For each element in the array (each line) 
    print "$file[$i+1]" if ($file[$i] =~ /$match/); # Print the next line if the current line matches your match variable
}
```

Output:

```
'/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/141163.php'
'/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/images/120541.php'
'/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/administrator/components/com_mynetwork/language/200724.php'
'/home/avocatma/public_html/raul/mambo/components/com_mynetwork/228469.php'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
perl -ne'
  BEGIN{ ($m) = map qr/$_/, quotemeta pop }
  print if $ok;
  $ok = /$m/;
' logfile "# Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP Exploit [P0008]]:"
```

it will print line after line matching `# Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP Exploit [P0008]]:`

Comment: `map qr/$_/, quotemeta pop` is perhaps better written `qr/\Q$ARGV[-1]/`.

Comment: No, variables are interpolated inside `\Q...\E`.

Comment: @TLP perhaps `map qr/\Q$_/, pop` as it needs to remove last element from `@ARGV`

Comment: In a one-liner, you don't really need to have argument strings anyway.

Comment: ...since its all typed in at the same time, that is.

Answer (score 0):

What did you try?

You can always keep the previous line in a variable and to print the current line only if the previous one match "what you want".

In a script, it could be something similar to:

```
my $file, $line, $preline;
open($file, "<", "your_file") || die "can't open $file\n";
while (<>) {
    $preline = $line;
    $line = $_;
    if ($preline =~ /what_you_want/) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps to write a first try. In addition to these code lines, don't forget to use "strict" and "warnings"! ;-)